# Common mode choke - alternative part

Tags: common-mode-choke

I have sent out a PCB for manufacture and the manufacturer has suggested an alternative part.

The application is a mains powered (220V AC 50Hz) device. The common mode choke is being used to filter EMI on the power lines.

The original CMC is a 30mH min @1kHz with a DC resistance of 0.76ohms.

The suggested alternative is 25mH min @1kHz with a DC resistance of 3ohms.

I raised a concern that the DC resistance was larger than the original part so they suggested they change the wire from 0.25mm to 0.3mm.

My Question is - what will this do to the DC resistance of the CMC and will it bring it closer to the specification of the original part?

I am new to the use of common mode chokes and could not find resources that mention the wire thickness - happy to look over any resources you can suggest to understand this better.

Comment: `what will this do to the DC resistance of the CMC and will it bring it closer to the specification of the original part?` - it will lower it but only to about 2.1 ohm and nowhere near the 0.76 ohm of the original part.

Comment: What is the specification the CMC has to meet? That's the important question. 2 ohms or even 3 ohms may be OK, depending on what current you are drawing.

Comment: The power of the device wont exceed 100W (a 480ohm load)

Comment: If you have already done your emissions (i.e. EMI) testing with the original part, changing this choke will effectively void the test and you have to re-do it.  (Or risk shipping a non-compliant product)

Comment: Fortunately it hasnt gone through any EMI testing yet